# Multithreading manager

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to write a class able to manage threads in order to parallelize processes in a loop.

It's the first time I use multithreading in C++, could you tell me if I'm misunderstanding something ?

(to make the code shorter, I've written the definitions directly inside the class, it will be changed later)

```cpp
using namespace std;

struct ManagedThread
{
    unique_ptr<thread> m_thread;
    bool m_terminated;

    ManagedThread(unique_ptr<thread> thread, bool terminated = false)
        : m_thread(move(thread)), m_terminated(terminated)
    {}
};

class ThreadsManager
{
    mutex m_threadsMutex;
    vector<unique_ptr<ManagedThread>> m_threads;

    mutex m_answerMutex;
    string m_answer;
public:

    void setAnswer(const string& answer)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(m_answerMutex);
        m_answer = answer;
    }

    string getAnswer() const
    {
        // i don't know if the mutex is needed here
        return m_answer;
    }

    bool isStopFlagSet()
    {
        return ("" != m_answer);
    }

    void markAsTerminated(const thread::id& id)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(m_threadsMutex);
        vector<unique_ptr<ManagedThread>>::iterator it(m_threads.begin());
        while(it != m_threads.end() && (*it)->m_thread->get_id() != id)
            ++it;

        if(it == m_threads.end())
            return;

        (*it)->m_terminated = true;
    }

    void waitForAvailableThread()
    {
        cout << "waiting..................................." << endl;
        while(!aThreadIsTerminated())
            this_thread::yield();

        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuardThreads(m_threadsMutex);

        vector<unique_ptr<ManagedThread>>::iterator it(m_threads.begin());
        while(it != m_threads.end() && !((*it)->m_terminated))
            ++it;
        (*it)->m_thread->join();

        m_threads.erase(it);
    }

    bool aThreadIsAvailable()
    {
        return (thread::hardware_concurrency() - m_threads.size() > 0);
    }

    bool addThread(unique_ptr<thread> t)
    {
        cout << "nb currently running : " << m_threads.size() << endl;
        cout << " ----- " << endl;
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuardThreads(m_threadsMutex);

        vector<unique_ptr<ManagedThread>>::iterator it(m_threads.begin());
        while(it != m_threads.end() && (*it)->m_thread != t)
            ++it;

        if(it == m_threads.end() && m_threads.size() < thread::hardware_concurrency())
        {
            m_threads.push_back(make_unique<ManagedThread>(move(t)));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void waitForEndOfAllThreads()
    {
        for(const unique_ptr<ManagedThread>& mt : m_threads)
            mt->m_thread->join();
    }

private:
    bool aThreadIsTerminated()
    {
        for(vector<unique_ptr<ManagedThread>>::iterator it(m_threads.begin()); it != m_threads.end(); ++it)
            if((*it)->m_terminated)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
};


void foo(int i, ThreadsManager& threadManager)
{
    for(unsigned j(0); j < 10*i && !threadManager.isStopFlagSet(); ++j)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        if(5 == i)
        {
            cout << "5 finds the answer" << endl;
            threadManager.setAnswer("theAnswer");
        }
    }
    cout << "fin : " << i << endl;
    // lets say the 5th thread finds the answer
    threadManager.markAsTerminated(this_thread::get_id());
}

int main()
{
    ThreadsManager allThreads;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;

    for(unsigned i(0); i < 10 && !allThreads.isStopFlagSet(); ++i)
    {
        if(!allThreads.aThreadIsAvailable())
            allThreads.waitForAvailableThread();

        cout << "start " << i << endl;
        allThreads.addThread(make_unique<thread>(foo, i, ref(allThreads)));
    }
    allThreads.waitForEndOfAllThreads(); // all the threads will end

    cout << "the answer is : " << allThreads.getAnswer() << endl;

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << duration << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this ThreadManager. What is it supposed to do? What is it's purpose?

Comment: I have writen a program running slow processes in a loop (5 seconds for the first loop, 40 seconds for the second loop, 320 seconds for the third...) and i would like to parallelize these independant processes

Comment: This is a general question that can be done in many ways. What does the class you posted is meant to do?

Comment: You should check out a classic thread-pool implementation. 100% it will perform better and be easier to use.

Comment: Honestly, if you want to write modern C++ multithreading code, then buy **C++ Concurrency in Action** by **Anthony Williams**. You probably don't need to have a thread manager as the standard library already has many tools for multithreading.  This is particularly true as you are new to multithreading.

Comment: Also there is a lot of existing libraries if standard ones are not enough. See for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `if(thread::hardware_concurrency() < 2)` should be written inside the class. Because this involves implementation details, it should be hidden from the user.
2. In fact, if `thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns 1, you can still use multithreading, but it is fully soft-scheduled by the OS, not hard-scheduled by the CPU. So I think this determination is unnecessary.
3. I think you forgot to post the constructor and destructor of the class.
4. The correct way to lock multiple `std::mutex`s is to use `std::scoped_lock`.
5. `waitForAvailableThread` has some bugs. If `while(it != m_threads.end() && (*it)->get_id() != terminatedThread)` does not find the `terminatedThread`, the program may crash next.
6. Using `std::make_shared` is better. `allThreads.addThread(std::make_shared<thread>(foo, i, ref(allThreads)));`
7. Why does `unsigned aThreadIsAvailable()` not return `bool`?
8. I don't think you need two `std::vector`s and two `std::mutex`s at all. You can store thread structures in just one `std::vector`, and then use a struct member to control whether the thread is terminated or not. I think it's better this way.
9. ......

In the end, I think there is something very wrong with the design of `ThreadsManager` and I recommend that you choose a good open source library to start learning.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I didn't understand what is the purpose of this class `ThreadsManager`... what is being reviewed? What is it meant to do?

Comment: @ALX23z I guess he(she) wants to synchronize the number of running threads with the number of threads supported by the CPU and be able to wait for all threads to exit, etc. Yeah, I'm a little confused about that too, so I think there's a big problem with the class design.

Comment: what could the constructor and destructor do ?

Comment: In my case, I know that one of the loop will find the result I want, but it's impossible to know which one will do. I have update the question with the version of this code.

Comment: the current behavior is exactly what I want but I would like to know if I can improve this code (Almost certain it's far (far far far) from being perfect !!)